# Creating XML from java classes with JAXB - how to use minOccurs and maxOccurs

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a pretty large set of Java classes, many that stem from each other. I want to know how to specify in the java code (with an annotation) when a certain property of a class is limited. For example, a vehicle.java class should only be able to have 1 manufacturer and 2-4 wheels.

I have come across minOccurs and maxOccurs in generated XML schemas, but I'm not sure what anootations in java code caused these to appear.

I tried putting @XmlElement(name"manufacturer", minOccurs="0") in my java code in the Car class, but minOccurs throws an error.

Thanks.

Comment: and where do you want the limitation to be enforced? When serializing/deserializing to/from XML, or also when the class is used by other classes?

Comment: I need to put the minOccurs/maxOccurs annotations in the Java code so when converted to XML it appears there

Comment: So, no unicycles (1 wheel), hovercraft (0 wheels) or trucks (18 wheels)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `@XMLElement(required=false)` which should give you a minOccurs of 0

Comment: I saw this, but I also need to set maxOccurs